# Media query style overwrite parent without detect

Tags: css, html, media-queries

So I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vu64/

I was currently implementing my queries for my dummy site which were working fine until I added the following below. As seen in the fiddle it seems that #header adapts to the media query header width at any resolution. I remove it, it works fine no problem. I can't seem to figure out the culprit. Thanks.

```
@media (min-width: 325px) {
    #contain {
        width:285px;
    }
    #header {
        width:285px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

Use: `max-width`

```
@media (max-width: 325px) {
   #contain {
      width:285px;
   }
   #header {
      width:285px;
   }
}
```

Also, I would suggest using Percentage and give a default width.
For example:

```
#contain{
   width: yyyypx;
}
```

Then do media queries for max-width. One more thing, you are doing device width - I would suggest screen width